# Selenium Server and Chrome Driver - Using Foxy Proxy addon

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using Selenium Server to drive Firefox and Chrome to run tests.  Both FF and Chrome have FoxyProxy extensions installed in order to work properly.

FF works great, I load the Selenium Server and it starts FF with the correct profile using the `-Dwebdriver.firefix.profile=myprofile` option when running the `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar`

With Chrome, I have FoxyProxy setup and it works properly if I run it manually.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to launch the Selenium Server + ChromDriver so that Chrome loads the FoxyProxy extension and uses the configuration I have setup.

I'm running it like this:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=".\chromedriver.exe" -port 4447`

My test gets a 404 b/c FoxyProxy is not loaded.  Any suggestions?